# Need to Replicate dict data inside array

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
json_data = {"map":[{"name":"test"}]}


def replicator(data, replica=1):
    final_data = {}
    for each_map_tcs in data.keys():
        for each_tc in data[each_map_tcs]:
            for i in range(replica):
                if each_map_tcs not in final_data.keys():
                    final_data[each_map_tcs] = []

                final_data[each_map_tcs].append(each_tc)
                each_tc['name'] += '-' + str(i)

    print(final_data)   

replicator(json_data, 2)
```

Actual output:
{'map': [{'name': 'test-01'}, {'name': 'test-01'}]}

Required output :
{'map': [{'name': 'test-0'}, {'name': 'test-1'}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import copy

json_data = {"map":[{"name":"test"}]}


def replicator(data, replica=1):
    final_data = {}
    for each_map_tcs in data.keys():
        for each_tc in data[each_map_tcs]:
            for i in range(replica):
                if each_map_tcs not in final_data.keys():
                    final_data[each_map_tcs] = []

                tmp_dict = copy.deepcopy(each_tc)
                tmp_dict['name'] += '-' + str(i)
                final_data[each_map_tcs].append(tmp_dict)

    print(final_data)   

replicator(json_data, 2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you just want to create a `list-of-dicts` to be the value of the larger dict.

the list part can be created with `list comprehension` which you can then incorporate into the dict like this:

```py
l = [{'name': 'test-0' + str(x)} for x in range(2)]
d = {'map':l}
print(d)
```

result:

```
{'map': [{'name': 'test-00'}, {'name': 'test-01'}]}
```

Comment: if we use this method, it ends up mutate dict(l) as well.

Comment: I ended up using copy library, for deepcopy, so that doe not mutates the original dict.